# Ignore terraform remote state

Tags: terraform

I accidentally delete remote file from S3, How do I push my local file ? I tried terraform remote push -force. It throws below error.

```
Failed to load state: Remote state found, but state file 'terraform.tfstate' also present.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that you have two state files in your local directory, something like this:

`.terraform/terraform.tfstate
terraform.tfstate`

If so, the one at `.terraform/terraform.tfstate` is a local copy of the s3 remote state. The one at `terraform.tfstate` is purely local state. But terraform only expects to see one or the other, hence the error message.

Copy both files somewhere safe, then try to decide which one to copy back to `.terraform/terraform.tfstate`. It may be obvious: one may be much newer or much larger than the other.

If all else fails, copy one at a time to `.terraform/terraform.tfstate` and `terraform refresh`, then keep whichever version works better.

Comment: And then turn on bucket versioning for the S3 bucket you use for these files.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to manually bump the serial number in your local state cache (.terraform/terraform.tfstate) to a value over the current serial number then try again